# Applying Blahut-Arimoto Algorithm for Continuous Channels Capacity Calculation

Tags: statistics, algorithms, information-theory, mutual-information

I am exploring the Blahut-Arimoto algorithm for channel capacity calculations, particularly for continuous channels. I understand its application in discrete scenarios, but I am unsure about its adaptation to continuous channels. Could someone provide insights or a step-by-step guide on how to apply the Blahut-Arimoto algorithm for continuous channel capacity calculations? Additionally, are there any specific considerations or modifications needed for the algorithm in the continuous case? Your expertise and guidance would be greatly appreciated!